# I want to send email attachment using nodemailer in node js.i am using elasticemail gate way

Tags: node.js

I need to send a URL attachment in nodemailer.i try to many ways but mail was not deliverd.I was seen elasticemail gateway they showed a error like this "suppressed" how will i solve this issue

```
attachments:[{   // use URL as an attachment
filename:'GSTR3B_33ADQFS8223E1ZY_012019_1551501263.pdf',
path:'my url'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting "suppressed" from Elastic Email check in the Contacts section on your dashboard to be sure that the contact is in an "Active" state. The contact might be suppressed by the system.